# D3.js create a dynamic color() function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, pie-chart

I am working on [this pie-chart](http://bl.ocks.org/Federicopvs/9ff8aec6c7aee9862ddc) in D3.js.
This is the data:

```
DATA.JSON
[
{
"key":"amministrazione",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":404571081,
"val2013":374545999
},
{
"key":"sociale",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":235251679,
"val2013":258973653
},
{
"key":"territorio e ambiente",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":286164667,
"val2013":274949400
},
{
"key":"viabilità e trasporti",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":144185664,
"val2013":140619534
},
{
"key":"istruzione",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":168774925,
"val2013":170016208
},
{
"key":"cultura",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":55868045,
"val2013":55735535
},
{
"key":"sport",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":27219432,
"val2013":31244800
},
{
"key":"turismo",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":9544845,
"val2013":7674419
},
{
"key":"sviluppo economico",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":14790363,
"val2013":16635868
},
{
"key":"servizi produttivi",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":4334,
"val2013":4440
},
{
"key":"polizia locale",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":99007202,
"val2013":102065987
},
{
"key":"giustizia",
"categoria":"funzioni",
"val2015":12147068,
"val2013":12880138
},
{
"key":"anticipazioni di cassa",
"categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
"val2015":304323808,
"val2013":304323808
},
{
"key":"finanziamenti a breve termine",
"categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
"val2015":0,
"val2013":0
},
{
"key":"prestiti obbligazionari",
"categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
"val2015":38842996,
"val2013":36652213
},
{
"key":"quota capitale di debiti pluriennali",
"categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
"val2015":0,
"val2013":47152
},
{
"key":"quota capitale di mutui e prestiti",
"categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
"val2015":128508755,
"val2013":329885961
},
{
"key":"spese per conto terzi",
"categoria":"altro",
"val2015":232661261,
"val2013":236921438
},
{
"key":"disavanzo di amministrazione",
"categoria":"altro",
"val2015":0,
"val2013":0
}
]
```

It shows how the governmental budget is allocated to different functions (i.e. "key"). A value is given for each year (e.g. "val2015", "val2013") and each function is part of a macro-category (i.e. "funzioni", "rimborso prestiti", or "altro").

I am trying to create a color() function that dynamically changes its domain and range depending on:

1. the colorRange arbitrarily assigned as domain: greenRange for "funzioni", redRange for "rimborso prestiti" and blueRange for "altro"
2. the number of functions ("key") in each category that have a positive value, thus ignoring functions for which no resources were allocate during a given year. Done through the count() function (which works)
3. Then creates X number of shades for each ranging depending on the count() function of point 2
4. And assigns the appropriate color to each of the pie's wedges

This is my starting point:

```
var greenRange = ["rgb(199,233,192)", "rgb(0,68,27)"]; //range for the first 12 wedges of the pie (assuming they are all >0)
var redRange = ["rgb(252,187,161)", "rgb(103,0,13)"]; //range for the following 5 wedges of the pie (same assumption)
var blueRange = ["rgb(198,219,239)", "rgb(8,48,107)"]; //range for the last 3 wedges of the pie (same assumption)
```

I tried two options but neither works.

**OPTION 1**

```
function draw () {

//(1) count the number of data points with value > 0 in each category - This works well!
var countFunzioni=0;
dataset.forEach (function (d) {if (d.categoria=="funzioni" && d.val2015>0) { countFunzioni += 1;}})

var countRimborso=0;
dataset.forEach (function (d) {if (d.categoria=="rimborso prestiti" && d.val2015>0) { countRimborso += 1;}})

var countAltro=0;
dataset.forEach (function (d) {if (d.categoria=="altro" && d.val2015>0) { countAltro += 1;}})

//(2) create a color method for each category based on a the count calculated above and the range I determined
var colorFunzioni = d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0, countFunzioni])
         .range(redRange);

var colorRimborso = d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0, countRimborso])
         .range(redRange); 

var colorAltro = d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0, countAltro])
         .range(blueRange);

//draw the chart
chart = d3.select("#visualizationInner")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("id", "visualization")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

//draw and color the paths
var path = chart.datum(dataset).selectAll("path")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            //(3) return the appropriate color method depending on the datum's category
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
              if (d.data.categoria=="funzioni") {return colorFunzioni(i);}
              else if (d.data.categoria=="rimborso prestiti") {return colorRimborso(i);}
              else if (d.data.categoria=="altro") {return colorAltro(i);}
            })
            .style("fill-opacity", 0.75)
            .attr("d", arc);
}
```

Which returns this result:

[image]

This goes close, however it assigns a range of red colors to the first 12 wedges (which should get the greenRange instead) and no color to the wedges pertaining to the other categoreis

**OPTION 2**

```
function draw () {

//(1) same as above

//(2) create a color method that adapts to each category's count and range
  var color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, function (d) {
          if (d.data.categoria=="funzioni") {return countFunzioni;}
          else if (d.data.categoria=="rimborso prestiti") {return countRimborso;}
          else if (d.data.categoria=="altro") {return countAltro;}
        }])
        .range(function (d) {
          if (d.cdata.ategoria=="funzioni") {return greenRange;}
          else if (d.data.categoria=="rimborso prestiti") {return redRange;}
          else if (d.data.categoria=="altro") {return blueRange;}
        });

////(3) return the appropriate color method depending on the datum's category
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return color(i);}
}
```

[image]

This does not get any coloring done.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option1 Remarks:

```
       .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
          if (d.data.categoria=="funzioni") {return colorFunzioni(i);}
          else if (d.data.categoria=="rimborso prestiti") {return colorRimborso(i);}
          else if (d.data.categoria=="altro") {return colorAltro(i);}
        })
```

The trouble is the above is written as if 'i' will maintain separate tallies for the three categories. It doesn't though, it keeps an index for all elements in your selection, and as soon as the first 12 items in the selections are done, the next items are going to be out of range of any of the scales you described and return "#000000" - this is why the first 12 are coloured (and the first 12 may be red because you assign the red range to two scales, and the green range isn't used) and the rest aren't.

As a quick fix, keep a tally in the data itself of where it occurs in each category like this:

```
dataset.forEach (function (d) {if (d.categoria=="altro" && d.val2015>0) { countAltro += 1; d.catIndex = countAltro; }})
```

do this for each category

and then in the fill attr function do:

```
else if (d.data.categoria=="altro") {return colorAltro(d.data.catIndex);}
```

and again that needs done for each category.

---

As a separate thing, you can get rid of those else-if's by assigning the colors like this:

```
var colorMap = {
    funzioni: colorFunzioni, 
    altro: colorAltro, 
    "rimborso prestiti": colorRimborso
}
```

and then later doing

```
       .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
          var scale = colorMap[d.data.categoria];
          if (scale) return scale(d.data.catIndex)
        })
```

Comment: You are my hero!! thanks a lot!! you both solve something I've been banging my head on for days and showed me a very useful method with colorMap. I understand it is basically a dictionary that associates a key to a value right? however, I do not understand how the accessor function uses it. Could you please point to some resources to find out more? I feel this could be very useful in the future

Comment: Yes it's just a object using the strings in the categoria field as keys to point to the colour sclaes. So when you access it with [d.data.categoria] it should fetch the right colour scale from that object

Comment: What I do not understand is `if (scale) return scale(d.data.catIndex);`.. I added the semi-colon, is that correct?... sorry if seems a trivial question but I'd like to fully understand the code.

Comment: `if (scale)` just tests to see if a colour scale has been returned - if one of your items suddenly has a new category name that has no entry in the colorMap then it will fail that if statement. If it does have a scale then it just calls it with the index value of the item for its category to return a colour.